# Applying Transaction Logs to an existing Database

Tags: sql-server, restore, transaction-log

I am wondering if this possible, I can not seem to apply another transaction log.

I have restored the Full database backup, the differential backup and my last Transaction Log `WITH RECOVERY`. If later on I need to apply the next Transaction Log in sequence to it, what do I need to do?

I tried applying the Transaction Log and it states:

> The log or differential backup cannot be restored because no files are ready to rollforward.

For each time I need to add a new Transaction Log, do I have to go through the steps of restoring the backup database, restoring the differential database and all transaction logs again?

Comment: @Lennart the error message is SQL Server

Answer (score 4):

You have to start over and restore full and diffs with no recovery and then the tlogs  with `stand by` option. This will allow you to restore tlogs later as well.

You can configure logshipping with option of `stand by`, so you can read from the secondary database.

There will be a `.tuf` (transaction undo file) file created when you restore tlogs with standby option.

For manually restoring tlogs use [restore gene](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/sp_restoregene/) or you can just use logshipping for automated restores.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to apply additional transaction logs you will need to start back at your full backup. To quote MSDN,

> The database cannot be recovered until after the final transaction log has been applied. If you recover the database after restoring one of the intermediate transaction log backups, that before the end of the log chain, you cannot restore the database past that point without restarting the complete restore sequence, starting with the full database backup.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189596.aspx

Comment: OMG, thanks for the answer..... This will be a major pain because I have over 400 Transaction Log files and more every day. When I really only need to add any new Transaction Logs (this is a read only database so the only new data is whatever I load from the NEW Transaction Logs).

Comment: You can script the restore which will make those 400 files a bit more manageable. Try something like https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1584/auto-generate-sql-server-restore-script-from-backup-files-in-a-directory/ or http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Restore/95839/

Comment: Is this not a candidate for log shipping?

Comment: Yea, I think that would do it.. I never knew that was what it was called. Hmmm will just have to research on how to do it. Thanks Rob!

Comment: Would I be able to use their Full Database Backup to start this process?

Comment: To clear things up @image13, can you add some details to your question, like which DBMS (I'm assuming SQL Server) and version you are using? Also, the purpose of the restore. Are you restoring to a reporting server? A test\dev server? Recovering the production server?